# Count occurences in a list and return it in another list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to do a function called countAll. This function should get a list of numbers and return a list (element,number of occurences). For example :
countAll [1,2,3,4,4,4] should return 
[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,3)]
I am forced to use function count which i posted below.

```
count :: Eq a=> a -> [a] -> Int
count e [] = 0
count e (x:xs) 
 | e == x = 1 + count e xs
 | otherwise = count e xs
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way of doing it is with [list comprehension](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension):

```
countAll xs = nub [(x, count x xs) | x <- xs]
```

`nub` removes the duplicates and you will need to `import Data.List (nub)` to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a fast data-structure, for example `Data.IntMultiSet`. Let `ls = [1,2,3,4,4,4]`

```
import qualified Data.IntMultiSet as IntMultiSet

IntMultiSet.fromList ls
```

An alternative using `IntMap`:

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IntMap

IntMap.fromListWith (+) [(k,1) | k <- ls]
```

Comment: The original question did ask to use the function `count`. Also worth noting that this only works on ints - which may be sufficient, OP is not entirely clear, but `count` only assumes `Eq` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

We can do better than `nub` (which is `O(n^2)`) if the list elements are also instances of `Ord` without requiring the heavy machinery of an `IntMultiSet` by putting like elements together with `sort` and then grouping them into sublists with `group`. For example, `group . sort $ [1,2,3,4,4,4]` gives `[[1], [2], [3], [4,4,4]]`.

Once we have these items organized into sublists, we can count each sublist:

```
countAll = map (\(x:xs) -> (x, count x (x:xs))) . group . sort
```

(Note that `group` guarantees that there won't be any empty sublists so we know that we don't need to check the `[]` case in our mapped function even though the compiler does not.)

If we don't need to use `count`, we can instead use

```
countAll = map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . sort
```

or, with the handy `(&&&)` combinator from `Control.Arrow`,

```
countAll = map (head &&& length) . group . sort
```

Since an [association list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list) of elements with their counts is a handy way to represent a [bag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), I like to call this

```
bag = map (head &&& length) . group . sort
```

`bag` is `O(n log n)`, which is only a log factor worse than the `IntMultiSet` version.